# Django-Tastypie Advanced Filtering

Tags: django, rest, tastypie

I am using Django-Tastypie.

I have a URL like

```
/api/v1/pic/?event=25&format=json
```

This returns all photos for `?event=25`. But I have certain other things that it should take into consideration.

Like an event which is private(ie: `event.private=1`) it should do some kind of filtering on the photos that it returns. How do I implement it? Any pointers will be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

Can you be more specific?
What kind of filters do you want.

For private event filters you can define a Boolean field in the model:

=====================Models=====================

```
class Event(models.Model):
    private = models.BooleanField()
    ...

class Pic(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    ...
```

=====================Resources=====================

```
class PicResource(ModelResource):
    event = fields.ForeignKey(EventResource, 'event')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Pic.objects.all()
        filtering = {
            'event' : ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            'date' : ALL
        }
        ordering = ['date', 'event']
```

Then, you could query the resources:

1. All pics from private events - /api/v1/pic/?event__private=True&format=json
2. All pics ordered by date newest first - /api/v1/pic/?format=json&order_by=-date (note the "-" sign which indicates descending.

Comment: If the event is private(ie:event.private=True) it should then check all pics that have (pic.private=1) and return only those pics.

I doubt if this can be done with mere filters on URL, I guess I need to write some logic on the resources such that, if event(ex:event=25) is private then retrieve only private photos from that event.

Comment: You're right. You need to add logic on the resources side. but this can be done using tastypie's hooks, like "apply_filters" - http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#Resource.apply_filters, or "build_filters" - http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#id5

Answer (score 0):

I landed here looking for more general Tastypie filtering, so I thought I'd add a bit more to @ge7600's answer.

If you want to filter on fields you can use any valid Django query syntax in the url. If I've exposed these fields for filtering:

```
class PicResource(ModelResource):
    event = fields.ForeignKey(EventResource, 'event')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Pic.objects.all()
        filtering = {
            'event' : ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            'date' : ALL,
            'title' : ALL
        }
        ordering = ['date', 'event']
```

I can filter with the url parameters like:

```
/api/v1/pic/?event=25
/api/v1/pic/?title__contains=sunset
/api/v1/pic/?date__gte=2015-06-01&title__contains=wedding
```

If I read the docs more carefully I might have figured that out sooner...

Answer (score -1):

You just have to define [resource](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html).

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from tastypie import fields
from tastypie.authorization import DjangoAuthorization
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource, ALL, ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
from myapp.models import Entry


class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'auth/user'
        excludes = ['email', 'password', 'is_superuser']


class EntryResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Entry.objects.all()
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
        resource_name = 'myapp/entry'
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        filtering = {
            'slug': ALL,
            'user': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            'created': ['exact', 'range', 'gt', 'gte', 'lt', 'lte'],
        }
```